# ExpressionEngine Zoo Visitor field with Channel Images outputs four images for every one

Tags: expressionengine

I have a Zoo Visitor field called "member_gallery" which is a channel images field. Whenever I show the images, it creates 4 images for each one. However I do not want to output 4 images for each one. I want to output one image for each one. Here is the code I write:

```
{visitor:member_gallery}
   {exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}"}                        
       <img src="{image:url:large}" alt="{image:title}" />
   {/exp:channel_images:images}
{/visitor:member_gallery}
```

Here is the markup it spits out

```
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(1)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (1)" />                                           
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(1)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (1)" />                                           
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(1)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (1)" />                                           
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(1)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (1)" />

<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(2)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (2)" />                                           
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(2)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (2)" />                                           
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(2)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (2)" />                       
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(2)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (2)" />

<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(3)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (3)" />                                           
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(3)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (3)" />                                           
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(3)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (3)" />                                                   
<img src="http://staging.eventplanner.verityinteractive.com/images/19/images_(3)__large.jpeg" alt="Images (3)" />
```

To be clear, I do not want to display 4 images for every one. If you couldn't figure that out. To be extremely EXTREMELY clear, here is my question; How do I write this so I only get 1 image for each one I have uploaded, rather than 4? Thank you. I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: Hey Bobby, welcome! Would you mind elaborating on your question. Currently there doesn't seem to be a question at all in fact. Seems like you are showing us what you are getting though, are not explaining what you are trying to do and or what the actual problem is. We could guess though, that's very productive.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the channel entries tag within Zoo Visitor...

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have a loop inside a loop, hence the duplication. Have you tried removing the channel entries tag?